# Compile HTML template string in NativeScript core

Tags: nativescript

I have template string something like below in a variable:

```
viewModel.description =  "<p><strong>Hi</strong> helloo</p>";
```

I wanna compile it and show in view(using interpolation).

Something like:

```
<Label text="{{description}}" />
```

**EDIT :**

I replaced the `HTML` tags with `XML` tags using regular expressions. And now I want to compile those strings to show in the view.

Now I have something like below:

```
viewModel.description = "<Label>Hi</Label><TextView text="hello"></TextView>";
```

Now, how to show the data in view something like `ngBindHtml` in angular.

Thank you.

Comment: The html tags that you may be familiar with do not work in nativescript's xml. Open the docs http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/action-bar to see what you can use. If you want to style the string, you should consider using FormattedString or css styles.

Comment: @pkanev , I have updated the answer. Plese help me find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlview

```
<HtmlView :html="description"></HtmlView>
```